# Kingdoms of Amalur: A Contest

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This contest has ended. Congratulations to

- Raven Dreamer for asking the most viewed question: [What is the max
  level in Kingdoms of Amalur](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/what-is-the-max-level-in-kingdoms-of-amalur)?
- Sterno for giving the [answer with the highest score](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50003/how-can-i-maximize-my-skill-points-gained-in-kingdoms-of-amalur/50113#50113).

If you want to see the details of the contest, read below.

---

In honor of the release of Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning, we’re holding a contest.

To enter, ask or answer questions related to Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning as you play the game. Anything tagged [kingdoms-amalur-reckoning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-amalur-reckoning) is eligible for this contest.

**Prizes:**

[image: chair] [image: vita]

There will be two winners: the person who (1) asks the **most viewed question** and (2) the person who gives the **answer with the highest score.** Each of these people will receive either a Cohesion XP 11.2 Gaming Chair Ottoman with Wireless Audio or a PS Vita (whichever they prefer).

**The Rules:**

- The contest is open to both new and current gaming.stackexchange.com
  users.
- Everyone is eligible to participate regardless of geographic
  location. If you live in an area of the world where it is too
  difficult for us to ship you your prize, we’ll figure something else
  out on a case by case basis.
- The only metrics we’re using to determine winners are views and votes.
  So ask as many good questions and give as many good answers as you
  can, and share them using whatever means you see fit. Twitter,
  Facebook, Tumblr, Google Plus, whatever works for you.

**Dates:** The contest begins Tuesday February 7th at 12:01 am and goes until Friday, February 17th at 11:59 pm (UTC). Only questions and answers posted within that time period will count towards this contest.

Comment: Lets just hope this doesn't turn into another [funniest picture contest](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/36308/3) again.

Comment: @Resorath To be fair, I also had the 2nd highest answer, so it's a moot point.

Comment: its a shame I'll be skipping this one, good luck to all those who're going for it!

Comment: @sterno ~@ravenDreamer Congrats guys!!

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little confused by the winning conditions. You say:

> The people who (1) ask the most viewed question and (2) give the answer with the highest score will receive either a [...]

But then in the rules, there's:

> The only metrics we’re using to determine winners are the number of views your questions get and the sum of the votes your answers get.

Which is it? The person who asks the singular most viewed question or has the answer with the highest score, or the person who has the most views across all their questions or has the largest combined answer score?

Comment: Sounds like two winners to me, one for votes and one for views, but I agree it's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @MatthewRead There are two winners for sure; the question is how those two winners are determined. Is it for a single post, or is it for the combined activity in the tag?

Comment: Ah I see.  I just assumed it was combined activity, but again you're right that it's ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. There will be two winners: the person who asks the most viewed question, and the person who gives the answer with the highest score (two separate posts). When we said "sum of votes your answers get" we meant the total score. Changed it to be clearer (hopefully).

Comment: @Lauren Ah got it, thanks!

Comment: @Lauren This still reads weird, mainly because it sounds like you're writing it as someone disassociated from the gaming community. Based on the comments here I think you're using "You" to mean "You, the SE gaming community as a whole", but when an individual reads it, they take "You" to mean "my individual self". Thus, it reads like, for each individual, you'll total up their views across all their own individual questions, and answer upvotes among their own individual answers. I think the contest text, even after edit, still has the problem Mark described.

Comment: @Sterno maybe fixing this post is a job for EL&U haha! Just kidding. To clarify, there will be two winners: the person who asks the question that gets the most views, and the person who provides the answer that has the highest score.

Comment: @Lauren I think your new edit fixes the problem. I recommend updating the blog post too!