# The Leaguecraft ggClassic presented by Gaming.StackExchange (League of Legends tournament)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

> > > #### Note: The tournament has ended, but you can still [watch the VODs](http://www.own3d.tv/ggChronicle).  Look back for videos from the competition dates.

Stack Exchange is sponsoring a pro-level League of Legends tournament called the ggClassic. The ggClassic is a series of tournament matches beginning next week. Gaming Stack Exchange will get good exposure to Pro LoL teams, players and their followers through advertisements on the livestream and tournament materials. Check out the [ggChronicle](http://ggchronicle.com/the-leaguecraft-ggclassic-presented-by-gaming-stackexchange-a-new-5000-tournament-with-open-sign-ups/) for details on the tournament!

## Schedule Summary

- Ro32: **March 17 & 18**, beginning at 1 PM ET/6 PM GMT
- Ro16: **March 24 & 25**, 1 PM ET, 6 PM GMT
- Ro8: **March 31**, 12 PM ET/5 PM GMT
- Finals: **April 1**, 12 PM ET/5 PM GMT

### [<strike>Live Streams*</strike> and VODs](http://www.own3d.tv/ggChronicle)

<sup>*Only when live, obviously.</sup>

Comment: Btw stuff like that really makes me wish we had a better site name and domain name!

Comment: @Oak, perhaps we could revisit the issue... but I remember we had A LOT of trouble for even narrowing down the list of possibilities :)

Comment: @JuanManuel it's a hard decision to make, definitely. But when our name / domain name start appearing in sponsorship context, it becomes critical. We could just go with some name enforced from above by Stack Exchange employees, if it turns out deciding this is too problematic.

Comment: @Oak Oh, I was agreeing with you. I just would like it to be a better process than last time. Pinged you in chat.

Comment: Erm...were any of us allowed/wanted to play in this? From the looks of that article, signups ended over 10 days ago...

Comment: Yes, I'm confused by this; it looks like that announcement was February 28, open sign-ups closed March 3 and this is the first I've heard about it (granted I've been sparse as of late).

Comment: @Juan I still like StageSix

Comment: @JohnTheGreen This tournament is a pretty high level of play.  If you're at that level of play, I apologize for the unintended slight, but basically if you're not regularly playing as part of a team in significant tournaments this probably isn't for you.  If we *do* have people on the site at that level...AWESOME!  We should be sponsoring you and sending you to tournaments all the time.

Comment: @JohntheGreen thanks! Contest is now posted [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/league-of-legends-contest)

Comment: Judging by the number of LoL questions lately, this seems to be going well!

Answer (score 23):

I'm running this tournament along with the staff over at ggChronicle, and I just wanted to let you know that we'll be looking at your answers and comments here in order to guide our language as we discuss Gaming.StackExchange.

Please let us know what we can do to make the tournament better and to help build a more vibrant LoL Q&A community on this lovely site.

--MonteCristo

Comment: Excellent. Great to see you here MonteCristo.

Comment: If you have casters mentioning our site, I think it will be nice if they are encouraged to to take a look around the site and see how it works, if only for a few minutes (before the cast, of course). Would give more credence to the sponsorship, I guess... at least, if they don't end up hating us :)

Comment: I am one of the casters and we have had meetings with the other dozen or so about this site's functionality.  I think you will be pleased with how we promote Gaming.StackExchange on air, as we plan to run through quick tutorials on stream.

Comment: That's great to hear :)

Comment: I can confirm that these guys really did a great job plugging us during their casts, I'm really impressed with the support for their sponsors :-)

Comment: We're really happy to have a great sponsor like gaming.stackexchange and are glad that users liked our plugs.  It's pretty easy to be excited about your sponsor when you like the product that they offer!

Answer (score 8):

Do we maybe want to link directly to something like https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends
rather than to the home page?  Obviously we hope that people will eventually start exploring and learning that we have lots of other content too, but I think that would make a much better first impression in this context than coming to a home page that is dominated by Mass Effect 3 questions.

Comment: That makes sense!

Answer (score 7):

Can't edit Seth's meta post so posting this as an answer:

Just wanted to let everyone know that we are going to hold a small contest within the [League of Legends tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) to have something to point the tournament players to on our site. It will be pretty similar to the [Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3908/kingdoms-of-amalur-a-contest), and I'll announce it on meta shortly. Just want to have something to get the players using our site during their tournament! So keep an eye out.

Comment: Would you like someone with edit rep to add this to the main post?

Comment: sure, go for it if you're able!

Answer (score 6):

Winrar. Absolutely.

Just one comment - our advertisement there is:

> Our sponsor Gaming.StackExchange is a community-driven Q&A website dedicated to serving passionate video gamers, including League of Legends players.  Gain reputation by intelligently asking and answering questions, and increase your privileges on the site.  **Sign up and** help create a knowledge database for League of Legends and the other games you love!

(emphasis mine). I think it's maybe worth rephrasing this to remove the suggestion of signing up. Our site can be enjoyed almost fully without the need for signing up, while mentioning signing up right there on our advertisement is a turn-off, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, it's implying a barrier that's not entirely there. One of the collest things is that you can contribute without logging in.

Comment: Absolutely! That language shouldn't be used in the actual tournament communications, just is in this earlier blog post.