# League of Legends Contest!

Tags: discussion, contests

**Edit**: This round is now over. The next round will begin tomorrow, so check out [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/league-of-legends-contest-round-2) for the details and new prizes!

**Winners:**

- The most viewed question (viewed 276 times) was [What does SS stand
  for when an opponent is missing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/56530/16718) Prize goes to Blem!
- From the ggClassic, the most viewed question (viewed 168 times) was [Do any on hit effects from any champion abilities or items get affected by Spell Vamp?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/56649/16718) Prize goes to Illpalazzo!
- The answer with the highest score (16) is the accepted answer to [Is there a such thing as a Hexa Kill?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/56844/16718) This answer was also given by Blem! (Way to go!) Each user is only eligible for one prize, so the prize for the answer with the next highest score (12) goes to Raven Dreamer, for asking [Do any on hit effects from any champion abilities or items get affected by Spell Vamp?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/56661/16718)
- The winner of the raffle for 3500 Riot Points is Wingmind!

Winners will be contacted via email shortly.

---

The [Leaguecraft ggClassic](http://ggchronicle.com/the-leaguecraft-ggclassic-presented-by-gaming-stackexchange-a-new-5000-tournament-with-open-sign-ups/) is an awesome tournament filled with professional League of Legends gamers, and [we are the official sponsor](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/the-leaguecraft-ggclassic-presented-by-gaming-stackexchange-league-of-legends-t)! To show our support for the players as they do battle, we are giving away some awesome prizes to people who ask and answer the best questions about League of Legends. This contest is open to everyone participating in or watching the Leaguecraft ggClassic, as well as current users of Stack Gaming.

To enter: [play League of Legends](https://signup.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/index), and whenever you have a question about it, [ask it on Stack Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=league-of-legends). If you see another question that you know the answer to, help the gamer out and share your knowledge! Remember, you must tag the question [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) for it to be eligible for the contest. **Only questions tagged [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) and answers to those questions are eligible for these prizes.**

Prizes will be given to the people who (1) ask the most viewed question and (2) give the answer with the highest score. If you turn out to be one of these people, you will have your choice of **a new console system**! (up to $250)

[image]

If you don't win a new console, you will be entered into a raffle to win **3500 Riot Points!**

We will run a new round of this contest for each week of the tournament. The first round will go from March 17 at 12:01 am until March 21st at 11:59 pm (UTC).

If you heard about us because you're playing or watching the ggClassic, make sure you put "ggClassic" in the About Me section of your Stack Gaming profile, because we have separate prizes for you!

Notes

- Questions must be non-closed and non-deleted to count
- Everyone is eligible to participate regardless of geographic location. If you live in an area of the world where it's too difficult for us to ship you your prize, you may be asked to purchase it and be reimbursed by Stack Exchange.

Comment: 1) I assume the questions must be posted within said times?  2) Classic Xbox?  Really?

Comment: The console is your choice, I'll find a better pic. Yes, must be posted within the time period. Thanks! –

Comment: Reminds me of [the classic meme](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ub5v.jpg).

Comment: As LoL is a PC-only game, how about keeping with the theme and also  offer a graphics card with the same monetary limit?

Comment: @NickT: Don't forget about laptop gamers! Oh wait, apart from MXM 2.0b stuff there's not much to change.

Comment: @NickT that's a good idea - we'll be changing prizes for each round so I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: @Lauren as if to underscore the point: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=3864484#3864484 `:P`

Comment: So who won and when does the next one start?

Comment: @Blem Just updated! Congrats!

Comment: @Lauren Who is actually sponsoring this?

Comment: @Decency Stack Exchange is sponsoring the ggClassic and providing the prizes for these contests.