# Way of the Site to communicate events with users

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Well, I could not find another way to put it out.

Stackgaming is [sponsoring a League of Legends tournament](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/league-of-legends-contest), and I didn't even know it until the day of the event?

Yes the ME3 event is taking a lot of place right now, but would it be quite good to make an announcement banner (like the one's used for the SOPA protests) to make users know there is an event with the community. Or maybe use our ad space to do that.

Anyway, I do think the question has to be asked. How should StackGaming communicate smaller events it's supporting to its userbase?

Comment: The LoL tournament wasn't announced (to *us*) until 3 days ago, so don't feel too bad about not knowing about that one.

Comment: System messages are for extreme cases since they can't be dismissed.  SOPA is a little more important to the network than a contest.  There's feature requests on MSO to have something more in-between, similar to a badge notification, which you may want to support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The #1 thing you can do to stay on top of what's going on around the site is to stay on top of meta.  The [featured](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag in particular is always loaded down with interesting stuff that you should be aware of.

These things are also almost always pinned on the star list in chat as well.

Stay active on both Meta and chat, and you'll always be in the know!

Comment: Yeah, ok, message understood. But for users that visit the site every once in a while (not a regular like us), do they really know it when something happens in meta?

Comment: @Fredy31 [meta-tag:featured] questions from meta are pinned to the sidebar of the main site. Then again, nobody really knows they're there. I know I had no idea until very recently.

Comment: was the LoL event possiblity ever even a Featured meta post?

Answer (score 5):

There is a feature in progress to address this.  It is along the lines of the [community calendar proposed here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104309/should-so-se-have-a-community-calendar)  It should make it much easier to keep track of important events on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Meta would be the proper place.

Comment: I kinda disagree, since not everybody visits meta (like me)

Comment: @fredy31 Then you should visit meta more :)