# League of Legends Contest - Round 2

Tags: discussion, contests

**Edit:** This round is now over. The [final round](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4403/16718) begins today!

Winners:

- The most viewed question was: [What are the Key Gameplay Differences between Valve's DOTA 2 vs League of Legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/57739/16718) Prize goes to Resorath!
- The most viewed question from the ggClassic was: [When should you give up top tower for Dragon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/58351/16718) Prize goes to Blizzgrarg! (Psst - there's still an open bounty worth 50 rep for answering this question!)
- The [answer with the highest score](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/58268/16718) was to this question: How do you dodge Sivir's boomerang ability? (Check out that awesome illustration!) Prize goes to Tristan!
- From the ggClassic, the [answer with the highest score](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/58644/16718) was to this question: What are some effective ways to last hit better? Prize goes to Daniel Redford!
- The winner of the 3500 Riot Points is Andres!

Congratulations everyone! Winners will be contacted via email shortly.

---

The [Leaguecraft ggClassic](http://ggchronicle.com/the-leaguecraft-ggclassic-presented-by-gaming-stackexchange-a-new-5000-tournament-with-open-sign-ups/) is an awesome tournament filled with professional League of Legends gamers, and [we are the official sponsor](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/the-leaguecraft-ggclassic-presented-by-gaming-stackexchange-league-of-legends-t)! To show our support for the players as they do battle, we are giving away some awesome prizes to people who ask and answer the best questions about League of Legends. This contest is open to everyone participating in or watching the Leaguecraft ggClassic, as well as current users of Stack Gaming.

To enter: [play League of Legends](https://signup.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/index), and whenever you have a question about it, [ask it on Stack Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=league-of-legends). If you see another question that you know the answer to, help the gamer out and share your knowledge! Remember, you must tag the question [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) for it to be eligible for the contest. **Only questions tagged [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) and answers to those questions are eligible for these prizes.**

Prizes will be given to the people who (1) ask the most viewed question and (2) give the answer with the highest score. If you turn out to be one of these people, you will win a [Video Card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004O0OKXK)!

[image]

If you don't win a Video Card, you will be entered into a raffle to win **3500 Riot Points!**

We will run a new round of this contest for each week of the tournament. The second round will go from the time this post went up until March 28th at 11:59 pm (UTC). To see results from Round 1, check out [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/league-of-legends-contest).

If you heard about us because you're playing or watching the ggClassic, make sure you put "ggClassic" in the About Me section of your Stack Gaming profile, because we have separate prizes for you!

Notes

- Questions must be non-closed and non-deleted to count
- Everyone is eligible to participate regardless of geographic location. If you live in an area of the world where it's too difficult for us to ship you your prize, you may be asked to purchase it yourself and be reimbursed by Stack Exchange. If reimbursement via Paypal is not available in your country, you may be asked to choose a different prize from a vendor that will ship to you. We cannot guarantee that international shipping will always work, but we will do our best to accommodate special circumstances.
- Each user is only eligible for one prize per round.

**Edit**: I've been told that a few people posted questions immediately after seeing this contest announcement, so we will count all questions and answers that were made after the time this post went up for this round.

Comment: Would it be possible to get an equivalently-priced NVidia card? I happen to use multiple cards in my PC, and NVidia and ATI don't mix very well.

Comment: @StrixVaria Careful, you won't get very much performance without SLI anyways - and SLI should only be used on identical cards.

Comment: @Resorath I use different cards for different monitors (since I run more than 2 monitors). I'm not worried about SLI.

Comment: @StrixVaria - If you're running Windows 7, and you're only concerned about additional monitor outputs, they'll run together just fine, actually.  A card like this is pointless as a secondary to simply add outputs, though - it's way too loud and fast and uses too much power.  (Feel free to hit me up directly if you want more info - I deal with this a LOT professionally, and over at Super User)

Comment: If you don't need the video card, would it be possible to redeem your prize in RP?

Comment: Shouldn't this be featured?

Comment: @Lauren , I've been told I created my question three hours too early, I got my timezones (MST vs uh, GMT?) mixed up. Is it possible for [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57739/what-are-the-key-gameplay-differences-between-valves-dota-2-vs-league-of-legend) to still be in the running? I've been promoting the crap out of it. I created it as a knee-jerk reaction to this thread.

Comment: @Resorath will be happy to hear that :)

Comment: Is there a way to see who is winning?

Comment: Worst contest ever by the way...

Comment: Seems totaly lame to me that you can get an advantage by putting up a bounty!

Comment: I actually won o.o

Answer (score 2):

Isnt it kinda unfair that people can put bounties on their questions and then get loads of views?

Comment: My question had over 260 views when I first put up the bounty. I was getting a lot of views but baffled by the lack of answers. The 2k viewer though, roping in the dota 2 crowd, is both devious and ingenious.

Comment: Still, its gonna get feutured, so isnt it kinda like paying to get an advantage in a competition?

Comment: I'm relatively new to the site, having registered just a few days ago. I didn't know the feature option would get so much attention. I kinda assumed there would just be a red tag in the original list.

Comment: Bounties also prevent closure. (Closed questions are ineligible for the contest)

Comment: You can also edit questions or answers to essentially bump them to the front page, resulting in plenty of free visibility or votes. I didn't abuse this anywhere near as much as I could have and essentially gave Tristan the win when I bumped his topic. The contest was ridiculously exploitable and the format just doesn't make sense for here.

Comment: Bounties are a natural, built-in part of the site - their purpose is to get more views on the question so you can get a good answer. They do provide an advantage, but offering a bounty is an option for anyone, so in my opinion it's ok to allow bounties during contests.

Comment: Does a bounty give an advantage to views? Yes, certainly. Is it unfair in *that* aspect? Not really. A bounty is pretty much a demographically targetted view booster, but it is hardly the only available means. If you have a lot of online followers, a simple Tweet could easily triple the gains of a bounty. Likewise, posting on a place like Reddit to the right audience will result in a massive surge of views. You're allowed to work for views, you don't have to just sit back and pray that enough people look at it.

Comment: Not only that, but the point of the contest is to introduce people to Gaming.SE and how it works. Bounties are a core part of how StackExchange works. QED.