# How do you get entered into the giveaway on this site from ggChronicle?

Tags: discussion, contests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [League of Legends Contest - Round 2](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/league-of-legends-contest-round-2)

This highly confused me since the commentators who gave the information talk really fast and don't repeat themselves.

Comment: you can find more information here http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/league-of-legends-contest-round-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the reddit thread:

Our sponsors at Gaming.StackExchange.com will be giving out FREE VIDEO CARDS AND RP this weekend. **The Summoner or Summonette with the most viewed question and the highest rated answer tagged as League of Legends by March 28 will receive a video card worth up to $250 in value.** Questions must be posted on Gaming.StackExchange in order to enter. Furthermore, if you put the word "ggClassic" somewhere in your profile and receive two upvotes during the tournament, you will be eligible to win randomly distributed $25 RP cards.