# League of Legends Contest - Round 3 (Final Round)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

**Edit:** This contest officially ended last night. Winners are as follows:

- The most viewed question, [What do I do against the infamous “gank squad”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/60111/16718), was asked by Resorath.
- The most viewed question from the ggClassic, [What is the most important lane to carry a lane? (Mid, Bot AD, jungle, or Top)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/60431/16718), was asked by thizzle 71.
- The answer with the highest score was provided to Resorath's question above and can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/60116/16718). Way to go Deotronic, from the ggClassic!
- The answer with the next highest score was provided to [What is the theoretical maximum Attack Damage you can get?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/60911/16718) and can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/60914/16718). Way to go Ulxlx!
- The winner of the 3500 Riot Points is Trueflight!

Congrats! Winners will be contacted via email shortly. Thanks to everyone who participated!

---

The [Leaguecraft ggClassic](http://ggchronicle.com/the-leaguecraft-ggclassic-presented-by-gaming-stackexchange-a-new-5000-tournament-with-open-sign-ups/) is an awesome tournament filled with professional League of Legends gamers, and [we are the official sponsor](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/the-leaguecraft-ggclassic-presented-by-gaming-stackexchange-league-of-legends-t)! To show our support for the players as they do battle, we are giving away some awesome prizes to people who ask and answer the best questions about League of Legends. This contest is open to everyone participating in or watching the Leaguecraft ggClassic, as well as current users of Stack Gaming.

To enter: [play League of Legends](https://signup.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/index), and whenever you have a question about it, [ask it on Stack Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=league-of-legends). If you see another question that you know the answer to, help the gamer out and share your knowledge! Remember, you must tag the question [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) for it to be eligible for the contest. **Only questions tagged [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) and answers to those questions are eligible for these prizes.**

Prizes will be given to the people who (1) ask the most viewed question and (2) give the answer with the highest score. If you turn out to be one of these people, you will win either a [Solid State Drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064LFKNQ) or a [Samsung 27-inch LCD HDTV Monitor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032ANC00)!

[image: solid state drive] [image: monitor]

If you don't win the Solid State Drive or Monitor, you will be entered into a raffle to win **3500 Riot Points!**

We ran a new round of this contest each week of the tournament, and this is the final round. This round will go from the time this post went up until Monday, April 2nd at 11:59 pm (UTC). To see results from the previous round, check out [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4305/16718).

If you heard about us because you're playing or watching the ggClassic, make sure you put "ggClassic" in the About Me section of your Stack Gaming profile, because we have separate prizes for you!

Notes

- Posts must be non-closed, non-deleted, and have a positive score to count.
- Everyone is eligible to participate regardless of geographic location. If you live in an area of the world where it's too difficult for us to ship you your prize, you may be asked to purchase it yourself and be reimbursed by Stack Exchange. If reimbursement via Paypal is not available in your country, you may be asked to choose a different prize from a vendor that will ship to you. We cannot guarantee that international shipping will always work, but we will do our best to accommodate special circumstances.
- Each user is only eligible for one prize per round.

Game on!

Comment: So what's the deal with bounties?! People were complaining about them...

Comment: They prolly just ignored it! so time to exploit!

Comment: See comments to [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4404/16718) on the last round of the LoL contest

Comment: I dont understand.  I had the most views in the time this contest started as a person that came from the advertisement of the ggclassic.  My question is at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60031/what-is-the-best-way-to-land-skill-shots-at-short-range .

Comment: I am a GGclassic participant  I joined the site specifically from watching it and even put it in my username to promote the Tournament?

Comment: @GGClassic-Jona52 ok I think I figured it out. When we ran the query, we look for "ggClassic." It looks like you had "GG Classic" in your profile, with a space, so our query didn't pick it up. That's why I put it in quotes in my contest instructions - because it had to be exactly that word. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: I had it in 3 different places of my profile.  Now that you see it can you just do it manually? I even have a version without a space.

Comment: Sorry, you had it have it exactly as "ggClassic" in the About Me section of your profile at the time the contest ended. I think the instructions were pretty clear, otherwise I'd make an exception. Unfortunately I can't do that now.

Comment: On my gaming profile I have GGclassic right above where i wrote how i heard about the contest  its different than on the meta user profile I don't know why. I followed all the rules to the contest and have quadruple the views of the person you have as the winner.  You can clearly see just by clicking the LoL tag going through the newest filter who has the most views.

Comment: I see in your main profile you now have "ggClassic" as the first line, but that wasn't there when the contest ended (your main profile was the same as your meta at that time, I believe). Like I said, I'd like to make an exception because your question does actually have more views and is a good question, but it just didn't meet the search terms. I'm sorry.

Comment: I promoted the heck out of this website and the tournament on my facebook, my youtube channel, and through my many friends in the DoTA style gaming community.  This really puts a sour taste in my mouth when because a query doesn't find my question when its been featured for 2 days and you can see my name right there.  I even brought this up 3minutes after this was posted so that it could be corrected almost instantaneously.  There is no explaination that you have to have it exactly ggClassic because you will be using a query to find it outlined in the rules of the contest.

Comment: It's unfortunate that one of the most shallow Q&A's posted over the weekend received so many upvotes. I realize it's a crowdsourced site but the AD question and answer are of zero value. I feel like I shouldn't have spent so much time articulating myself and my opinions on a good, solid question and more time on one of the "lol what's this thingy do in league lol" questions. Frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

How does one know if they've won one of the randomly distributed RP cards?

Comment: It will be posted in this topic and the people who have won will be contacted by email

Comment: Thanks, Blem.  Any idea when that will be?

Comment: I guess it could take a day or two depending on how much work @Lauren got :)

Comment: Should be later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score -2):

So are people that have previously won with question views eligible for multiple prizes as long as its during different rounds?  It seems like they have the magic sauce or something =/.