# Can we do an event for Starcraft 2

Tags: support, site-promotion

Starcraft 2 Heart of the Swarm is coming out sooner than later, and I feel this game has enough reputation and prestige to easily compete with Diablo 3 or Mass Effect 3, of which both games had promotions on this website. Promotions are fun, and I'd very much like to see one for Heart of the Swarm. Is there something I can do to help this happen?

Comment: HoS is just an expansion tho...

Comment: @Lyrion You mean kind of like Mists of Pandaria? http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5197/mists-of-pandaria-beta-play-ask-answer-win

Comment: @bwarner I wouldn't know, I think Mists of Pandaria is more a "full" game... but I wouldn't know where to draw the line. I'm just thinking that there wouldn't be that much questions for HoS...

Comment: @Lyrion You can't play Mists without the base game. Mists introduced a new race and class, and new content. Likewise, HoS introduces new units and a new campaign. Seems like a pretty apt comparison to me.

Comment: I think the real advantage Starcraft has is the thriving e-sports scene. If we don't do a site promotion, we might consider sponsoring a tourney, like we did with League of Legends. Might be a chance to grab a lot more eyeballs as more people will be checking out the new content.

Comment: I guess there will be a lot of questions for the single player, especially with all those ridiculous achievements and how to get them. Most of the multiplayer stuff is covered by the teamliquid forum. But you could create a mini promotion offering 10% more points for questions regarding hots.

Comment: 10% more points? If you mean reputation points, that's not really how the site works. It wouldn't be a good idea to artificially inflate rep from posts about a particular subject, and it wouldn't work well with the way reputation actually works.

Comment: I suggest changing the title of this question to "Can we do an event for Starcraft 2?" or similar, since there will likely be a canonical meta post down the line for how to make promos happen. But this is unfortunately not that meta post, since the process isn't ready yet :)

Comment: @murgatroid99 I know that the reputation system does not work this way. But this is a "cheap" way to do a promotion that does not harm the community that much. I mean how much points can you get during a promotion anyways? If someone contributes like 2000 points during a one month promotion then he shall get the 200 points or a free "100 point bounty". The implementation is an easy SQL script that any programmer can hack in about 30 minutes, depending on the db schema.

Comment: @ayckoster When I say that's not how the reputation system works, I am pointing to the fact that all rep comes from somewhere, and it can always be recalculated to get the same value. They can't just give people extra rep because it has to come from somewhere. Plus, bounties only go to answers, and they are attached to specific answers, which would artificially inflate the importance of those answers. And I wouldn't want to give 100 free rep to anyone who posts 100 answers that barely make it to +1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Arqanoids! <strike>Arqadites? Arqadians. Hello, Arqadians!</strike>

Lemme address a few of the questions I see coming up here.

**Q: Can we do something for *Starcraft 2: Heart of the Swarm*?**
**A**: Possibly! Read on.

**Q: How about we sponsor a team or a tournament?**
**A**: Nope! You are correct that we've done this in the past, with [League of Legends](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/league-of-legends-contest) and [WoW Mists of Pandaria](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5197/mists-of-pandaria-beta-play-ask-answer-win). It's fun for the Arqade community, which is great! We like fun! Unfortunately, the sponsorship type activities are not a worthwhile investment for us. We spend a gazabajillion bucks on them and they only get us a relative handful of new users (some of whom are awesome! Hello, awesome new users!). We like spreading goodwill and happiness throughout the gaming community, but we'd rather focus on doing stuff for *you* guys that *also* attracts some good new users. (As [Business Cat](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mdyp0tzNU91qh66wqo1_500.jpg) would put it, the ROI is much higher when we focus on our community as opposed to on somebody's cousin's Team Fortress team.)

**Q: Hey, what happened to that Lauren person who used to hang around here? She used to make this stuff magically happen before we even knew we wanted it.**
**A**: She no longer works for Stack Exchange, and we're still pretty distraught about it, but learning to live without her. She left for a position at a younger, hipper NYC startup, and we have no problem with that. This unfortunately means that we no longer have an employee whose whole job it is to plan awesome stuff for the Arqade community. We do still want to keep doing awesome stuff centered around game releases, though. We just need to figure out a good way to make them happen regularly, and that's in the works.

**Q: That all sounds great. What's the outlook for Starcraft? Can we do something?**
**A**: Possibly! It comes out March 12, 2013. We have some cool stuff planned between now and then, so it's not something we will be able to focus on until January. In the meantime, the Arqade meta community can start to generate some ideas about what we might be able to do for a Starcraft event. **Or** you could discuss what else is coming out in March or April that you might prefer to celebrate. The options are practically boundless.

In the meantime, watch your meta for more formalized instructions about how we can choose events to celebrate and how to decide what to do for them.

Comment: I haven't had a new tshirt for months, please run a promotion so I don't have to do laundry...

Comment: Arqanoids is the proper term.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot, I sit corrected.

Comment: Arqadians is the more proper term.

Comment: @John, that's what I went with originally! Sounds like you guys need to wrestle for it.

Comment: Oh, there's no need to wrestle.  @OrigamiRobot knows he's wrong.

Comment: @JohntheGreen If by "he" you are referring to yourself.  I'll wrestle you any day of the week!

Comment: I think I'll let you two duke it out, and decide the correct term while you're distracted.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the correct term is "Arqanauts".

Comment: It's Febuary now. *bump*