# StarCraft 2 Heart of the Swarm Event

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, answer-swarm

A few months back I asked [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/can-we-do-an-event-for-starcraft-2) question about a HoTS event for Starcraft 2 and was told to check back around nowish. It's nowish. Let's bake this turkey!

..ok, @bapd deleted the question cause he's mean, but I shall endure! In the past year the site has seen several events focused on major title releases. Diablo 3 and Mass Effect 3 are two mentionable names that featured awesome events oriented on their title's release dates and fun activities for all, while promoting our site in a positive manner. I'd very much like to see a similar event for Starcraft 2: Heart of the Swarm. How can I help make this happen?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuNAE1AV4ls

Comment: +1. [tag:starcraft-2] *sustained* this site in it's early months.

Comment: If we're planning on doing a gaming grant, too, there are some other games coming out around the same time that might be valid.  SimCity for some, Monster Hunter 3U, to name a couple.

Comment: I've heard that the CHAOS team (who ran the previous D3/ME3/etc promotions)  has substantially changed since the Time of Many Promotions.  I don't know what that means exactly, but I'm willing to bet that it's less of a slam dunk than it was previously.  Who knows, though?

Comment: I'd be happy with Jin switching the UFO(ask question) to a mothership and maybe the walkers to goliaths oo and satellite dishes to turrets. But if you can get a whole event that'd be sweet too!

Comment: @badp thanks for restoring the original

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's already in the plans.

There are no details to be shared yet, but we will do some sort of a promotional Thing<sup>TM</sup> for Heart of the Swarm.

Stay tuned!

---

**Update:** We ran [AnswerSwarm](http://stackexchange.com/promos/13/answerswarm) when Heart of the Swarm was released.

Comment: Do the plans include a potential grant or should I just go ahead and purchase it? ;)

Comment: @jmfsg We won't be doing a grant for SC2, so go ahead and arrange your own copy.