# Why the hell did 30 League of Legends questions just get asked in a 5 minute span?

Tags: discussion

... I have no idea what's happening, but someone big probably linked to us.

Comment: I thought maybe there was a LoL update or something. I'm glad I'm not the only one that was a bit shocked by that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We're actually sponsoring a tournament.

[The Leaguecraft ggClassic presented by Gaming.StackExchange (League of Legends tournament)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/the-leaguecraft-ggclassic-presented-by-gaming-stackexchange-league-of-legends-t)

I'm going to put some more text here, so I don't get auto-converted to a comment as a "trivial answer". My answers are not trivial. :(